# search regex line by line and print multiple lines after match

Tags: python, regex

just started writing scripts.

I am trying to write 4 lines after matching a regex in the first line and do this through a very large file with thousands of lines.

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python
import sys
import string
import re

print"what file would you like to search?"
filename = sys.stdin.readline()
filename = filename.rstrip()
print "enter a barcode"
barcode=sys.stdin.readline()
barcode=barcode.rstrip()
regex=":0:"+barcode
infile = open(filename, "r")
outfile = open("sample_write.fastq", "w")
regex_object = re.compile(regex, re.I)
for line in infile:
   m=regex_object.search(line)
   if m:
      outfile.write(line)
exit
```

This writes the lines that have matched string (barcode) into my outfile, however, I need to write both the line with the barcode and the following 3 lines after the match into my target file. 
Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following to match

```
.*(BARCODE).*\n.*\n.*\n.*    //replace BARCODE with your variable
```

and write the matches (`\0`) to your target file

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tC0lJ0/4)

**Edit:** Use `regex =".*("+barcode+").*\n.*\n.*\n.*"`

Comment: but only first line of each record has the match anyway. and the rest are all different from record to record

Comment: if I replace regex line with

Comment: if I put regex =.*(barcode).*\n.*\n.*\n.* for the search, this regex did not work like mine

Comment: since my barcode is after :0: so I did this:regex=".*("+":0:"+barcode+")\n.*\n.*\n.*"  not finding anything, all empty lines, same with your line but I put :0:barcode as input line for searching

Comment: by the way ":0:" is to define where to look for barcode since the word would be everywhere if not defined to the specific location

Comment: I don't think it is working this way. no match found

Comment: Here are two reads:
NS500556:28:H23G2AFXX:1:11101:2051:1021 1:N:0:TGGTGA
GATGGNNGACGGGGAATCAGGGTTCGATTCCGGAGAGGGAGCCTG
+
AAAAA##F.FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF<FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF7F
NS500556:28:H23G2AFXX:1:11101:17766:1021 1:N:0:TCAGAG
GTCTTNNTGTGTGGTTCAAAATGGGCTCCAGCTGGTTGTGCCTCCT
+
<AAAA##FFFFFFFFFFAAAFFFFFFFFFAFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFAFFA
 
barcode is after "0:" in the first line of every 4 lines
if barcode = TGGTGA, then only the first read would come back into my output